# large eclipse Console Results java

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I am trying to view my results in java eclipse console but when I tried to view the results for 15*200 matrix the console show no results how ever when I reduce the size of the array to 15*100 the results is shown in the console I don't know why is this? and is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely seeing the console buffer size limit being reached. Eclipse, by default, has a limited number of characters it will show in the console.

If you go to Preferences > Run/Debug > Console, there's a "Limit console output" option. You can either uncheck that or increase the console buffer size.

Comment: thank you for replying but I already uncheck the "Limit console output" option and still have the problem